# How to learn transition type in a 1-hour extended DJ Mix?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, architecture

How would you design a model which learns the transitions in a given 1-hour DJ Mix? To be specific, the model should be able to learn transitions, specify the occurring time and the type (Crossfade, Infinite Loop, and so on). Data annotation is way too long since I have 3000+ DJ Mixes that are 1 hour long each, as mentioned. It's almost impossible to annotate the transitions in each mix without spending lots of money. Is there a way to do it unsupervised?